# Can a var be used twice?

Tags: javascript, var

I'm using the below code to take the total material cost and add sales tax to it then add any shipping costs and take that total value and populate it in the `materialtotal` field, and it works perfectly.

My issue is this, I now need to take the total from the `materialtotal` field and add it to the total of a field called `labortotal` and have that populate a field called `grandtotal`.

```
function tax(){
    var materialcost = document.getElementById( 'materialcost' ).value;
    var shipping = document.getElementById( 'shipping' ).value;
    var salestax = Math.round(((materialcost / 100) * 8.1)*100)/100;
    var materialtotal = (materialcost * 1) + (salestax * 1) + (shipping * 1);

    document.getElementById( 'materialcost' ).value = materialcost; 
    document.getElementById( 'salestax' ).value = salestax;
    document.getElementById( 'shipping' ).value = shipping;
    document.getElementById( 'materialtotal' ).value = materialtotal;
}
```

My problem is this I figured I could just add the `materialtotal` to a `var` such as this:

```
function getFinal(){
    var materialtotal = document.getElementById( 'materialtotal' ).value;
    var grandtotal = document.getElementById( 'grandtotal' ).value;
    var labortotal = document.getElementById( 'labortotal' ).value;
    var grandtotatal = (labortotal * 1) + (materialtotal * 1);

    document.getElementById( 'grandtotal' ).value = grandtotal;
    document.getElementById( 'labortotal' ).value = labortotal;
    document.getElementById( 'materialtotal' ).value = materialtotal;
}
```

When I add the

```
onpropertychange="getfinal()
```

to the materialtotal id tag it makes the browser lock up.

How can I get `materialtotal` and `labortotal` to total up and populate the `grandtotal` field?

Comment: `n*1 == n`. I don't get it... In any case, multiplication has higher precedence than addition, so you don't need the parentheses.

Comment: @elclanrs: Implicit coersion to `Number`.

Comment: Oh, I see now. Haven't seen that before. Just `+value`, that should do.

Comment: Don't use the `onpropertychange` event - it'll be triggered every time you set that input's value, causing an infinite loop

Comment: Correcting the spelling of "grandtotal" in getFinal() will probably help (it's spelled grandtotatal)

Comment: correcting the spelling of grandtotal didn't help the browser still locks up after input in the first box

Comment: Why are you updating `labortotal` and `materialtotal`? You're not changing their values.

Comment: that's what I want the onpropertychange to do, everytime that value changes in that box I want it to update the grandtotal. It works fine with everything else on the form except when trying to take the value of the materialtotal box and add it to the labortotal and get the grandtotal and I assume it's due to the fact I'm using the materialtotal in getting the sales tax first.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have this in a fiddle would you? That would help us help you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a property of the `materialtotal` element changes, you're calling `getFinal`. `getFinal` calculates some data and then modifies `materialtotal`'s `value`, which will then call `getFinal` again (and so on…)

Comment: Modifying a value in a script shouldn't trigger any more events, unless he's doing that manually

Comment: @appclay: I think the `onpropertychange` event will.

Comment: `oninput` is a better event handler

Comment: onpropertychange will trigger an event automatically if there is a change in the value of the box, it only works on IE though!

Comment: @JasonMcAdams: That's right, and as soon as a change is detected, you make another change, which is then detected, making another change, etc… That's why your code is locking up.

Comment: My bad... I didn't realise it was using `onpropertychange`, I assumed it was `onchange` or something else.

Comment: @JasonMcAdams: I'm not on Windows at the moment so I can't try it. Sorry.